# Unknown Error on embeding Stripe Pricing Table

Tags: html, stripe-payments

I have an error when I try to embed a stripe princing table on a web page.

When I copy the code provided by stripe during the cration of the pricing table and refresh the page it gives me unknown error. I used the HTML method to embed the pricing table.
Here my code :

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js">
      
    </script>
    <stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="{{PRICING_TABLE_ID}}"
    publishable-key="{{PUBLISHABLE_KEY}}">

    </stripe-pricing-table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you guys have any solution ?

Comment: It is possible that there is a problem with the way you have set up the pricing table ID and publishable key in your code. check that you are using the correct pricing table ID and publishable key for your Stripe account. Also make sure that you have linked the pricing table with the correct stripe account.

Comment: I verified all of them and they're all correct  but I have the same error

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test the pricing table in your local environment, you need to have have a local HTTP Server(e.g. Nginx, Apache).
The pricing table requires a website domain to render. You need to run a local HTTP server and host your website’s index.html file over the localhost domain.

More details can be found here [1].

[1] [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#limitations:~:text=Testing%20the%20pricing,server%20npm%20module](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#limitations:%7E:text=Testing%20the%20pricing,server%20npm%20module).